# Excel - split cell value by specific string?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have cells that contain a lot of text, but all of them contain string "RTG Actions: ". I would like to remove the text before the string ("RTG Actions: ") and keep only the text after it.

I have a formula that almost does the job:

```
=RIGHT(P6,LEN(P6)-FIND("RTG",P6))
```

Unfortunately it keeps also a part of the string with it. i.e. "TG Actions: eams will leverage the Command and Control framework to..."

Could you advise me, how can I remove "TG Actions: ", please?

Many thanks!

Comment: Just subtract `LEN("TG Actions: ")` from the second parameter of `RIGHT()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `RIGHT` or `MID` function (I prefer `MID` here):

```
=RIGHT(P6,LEN(P6)-FIND("RTG Actions:",P6)-LEN("RTG Actions:"))

=MID(P6, FIND("RTG Actions:",P6)+LEN("RTG Actions:"), LEN(P6))
```

For the `MID` `FIND` gets the beginning index of "RTG Actions:" and adds the length of it to get the starting point `LEN(P6)` ensures you get all the remaining characters.

Comment: Thanks Kevin! I didn't realize that.

Comment: Glad that worked. There are other ways also, but that make the most sense to me...

Comment: @Srpic Please note that `FIND` is case sensitive, so it will not work for "RTG actions" etc. You can mitigate this by using the `SEARCH` function, which is very similar.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option using the `SEARCH` function. It is essentially the same as the above, but just using a different function.

Since your string to search for is constant, I just swapped `LEN("RTG Actions: ")` with it's character count (13 if you include a lagging space)

```
=MID(P6,SEARCH("RTG Actions:",P6)+13,LEN(P6))
```